# Call a function if not an element was clicked in svg, but other elements using d3.js v5.4.0

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How could I call a function if not an element was clicked in `svg`, but other elements using `d3.js v5.4.0`?

For example, I would like the `alert` message to be displayed only when the `xhtml:input` is not clicked (and one of the other elements is clicked), but it shows up even if the `xhtml:input` was clicked as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/76uedo40/254/).

In other words I would like to preserve the functionality which is present in the fiddle, but prevent `alert` from being executed whenever the `xhtml:input` is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there's a `foreignObject` that can be looked for in `window.event.path` after a click.

Check this snippet

```js
var svg = d3.select("#drawRegion")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%");
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", "0")
  .attr("y", "0")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("fill", "yellow");

const fObj = svg
.append("foreignObject");
fObj
  .attr("x", "10%")
  .attr("y", "10%")
  .attr("width", "80%")
  .attr("height", "40%");
 
            const inputArea = fObj
                .append("xhtml:input");
            inputArea
                .style("position", "absolute")
                .style("top", 0)
                .style("width", "100%")
                .style("height", "100%")
                .style("border-radius", "40px")
                .style("border", "none")
                .style("text-align", "center")
                .style("outline", "none");

svg.on("mouseup.inputDialogueInteractionName touchend.inputDialogueInteractionName", function() {
  let isInput = false;
  window.event.path.forEach(function(pathObj){
   if (pathObj.tagName =="foreignObject") isInput = true;
  })
  if (!isInput) alert("not input")
  else console.log("input")
            });
```

```css
#drawRegion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="drawRegion">

</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What if I have more than one `foreignObject` in my document? Is it possible to perform a search based on, for example, an `id` attribute, but not a tag?